# find the upperbound for margin of error when estimating area using trapzoid method

Tags: calculus, integration, simpsons-rule

I am trying to find the margin of error upper limit when estimating the area under the function sin(x) with 10 partitions on bounds 0 to pi. I am using the trapezoid method and I can't seem to figure out this one because the second derivative is -sin(x).which is all - y values in this interval. I keep coming up with .0258 but the book shows .016476 is the answer. I don't know what to use for my K in k(b-a)cubed over 12(n squared). I tried using x= pi over 2, 0, and pi

Comment: I am reading other posts about error bounds which basically have the same method, I am looking at the graph of second derivative, and choosing the value of x which gives the highest y value. That y value is my K in the formula, in this case I come up with k =1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like I was getting the correct answer. The upper bound limit to the margin of error using 10 parts is .025838 to find this find the maxima of the second derivative which is x = pi over 2 in the interval 0 to pi this making y =1 so 1 becomes the value for k in the equation above... k*(b-a)^3 over 12*n^2